# Как отправить curl запрос с авторизацией используя php или Javascript?

Tags: php, curl

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как отправить нижеследующий запрос используя php или Javascript.

```
curl 'https://api-sandbox.homecredit.ru/oauth/token'  -u 'test_partner:test_partner_secret' POST  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Отправляю через консоль, получаю

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJhY2Nlc3MiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTA1MDAyMzQ1LCJqdGkiOiIwNjRjNWEyYy03ODY2LTRlMjQtYjJiMS1iNDFjNDJjZGU2YWQiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ0ZXN0X3BhcnRuZXIifQ.pkGK9LDsa6l4fsLV1kKHxUEWJIfZYjRIsuXmFCZjYBep1-Mn4Sdg1SjqMlA9kZt9DNDrwzItmMJF5KCYl4Eggf5dIrn3_v0QojEdRK5hvRkRm0tCzDrCThFkirzkZN7faFLP-4PrGBUGXYWNpUPo5O4XJeCK78qaXpqWzazQXV7nxctdJQjaKLqjHoga09zQsEvRHCvCkQhZ_pedjxU1Ehmyw-PGJstKVUafqnYzDb2GvIbNxH9ovr3dVwXNyvNnfbT-vdNbr8dOd4womaKttXGc6mLleoURcIIGWb8DWvrD6n00ltBfByNZcpvAt3Knymav-A5JxYDImDw8jM-CJw","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":39240,"scope":"access","jti":"064c5a2c-7866-4e24-b2b1-b41c42cde6ad"}
```

А через php нужного ответа не получаю. Приведите рабочий пример пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Кончено, вы вероятно не передаете POST данные.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://api-sandbox.homecredit.ru/oauth/token");
$data = array('grant_type'=> 'client_gredentials');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test_partner:test_partner_secret"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Я передаю пост. Пробовал разные способы. Приведите рабочий пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: А авторизацию вы передавали? Попробуйте вариант который я только что показал.

Comment: Нет, не работает.

Comment: Тогда все сложнее, при запросе который вы кидаете, с консоли, отследите все заголовки, и с эметируйте их в PHP, а ещё что отвечает страница на curl запрос из PHP?

Comment: Да нет никаких там заголовков. Все параметры в теме вопроса.

Comment: А что отвечает страница на curl PHP?

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /oauth/token on this server.

1

Comment: Ну если у Вас не получается как указал @ЕвгенийИванов тогда просто отправьте этот же запрос через `exec`